# Cassandra Time Series sort

Tags: cassandra, time-series, cql

I store my data in Cassandra NoSQL database with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE bidding3(
    item_id bigint,
    user_id bigint,
    bid_price bigint,
    current_time text,
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id,current_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (current_time,DESC);


CREATE TABLE bidding_user(
    item_id bigint,
    user_id bigint,
    bid_price bigint,
    current_time text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id,current_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (current_time,DESC);
```

And then I use 
`SELECT * FROM bidding_user LIMIT 5;`.
I would expect the data is arranged in time-series and it did for the first day, but things changed today.

```
Wed Jul 06 20:09:04 UTC 2016
Wed Jul 06 19:10:04 UTC 2016
Thu Jul 07 19:09:04 UTC 2016.
```

I think the database ignores the date but only care about the time.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM bidding_user LIMIT 5;
```

The problem here, is that you have not specified a `WHERE` clause.  Cassandra only maintains sort order within a partition key.  Your partition key is `user_id`, so my guess (since you are only showing us the `current_time` column, and not the `user_id`) is that your first two rows share a `user_id`, and the `user_id` for the third row is different.

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.timestamptest (
    userid text,
    activetime timestamp,
    value text,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, activetime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (activetime ASC)
```

If I query without a WHERE clause, I get:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT userid,activetime FROM timestamptest ;

 userid | activetime
--------+--------------------------
      a | 2015-09-25 11:33:33+0000
      a | 2015-10-22 14:26:00+0000
      c | 2015-12-28 19:12:00+0000
      d | 2016-01-22 14:57:54+0000
      d | 2016-01-22 14:57:54+0000
      d | 2016-07-07 19:44:04+0000
      b | 2015-10-22 14:26:00+0000
      b | 2016-07-07 19:44:10+0000

(8 rows)
```

As you can see, the order of my clustering key (`activetime`) is really only meaningful within each partition key (`userid`).

In other words, if you want your result set to be sorted, you will need to specify your `user_id` partition key in a `WHERE` clause with your query.

Not to self-promote or anything, but I wrote an article on this subject early last year, which may help you understand this better:

[PlanetCassandra: We Shall Have Order!](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/)

Answer (score 0):

The `current_time` is of type `text` so sorting is done based on characters of the date string.

Try changing the type of `current_time` to `timestamp`.